# F# Positional Arguments in Attributes

Tags: attributes, f#

I'm trying to create an attribute in F# with positional arguments but failing all the time.

```
type ColumnAttribute(?index:int,?name:string) =
    inherit Attribute()
    let mutable index = index
    let mutable name = name
    member x.Index 
        with get() = index
        and set value = index <- value
        member x.Name 
        with get() = name
        and set value = name <- value

type Substance = {
    [<Column(Index=1)>] Name : string
    [<Column(Index=0)>] Id : int
    [<Column(Name="sequence")>] Sequence : string
}
```

I've tried several different approaches but this is the closest I ended with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues that I see with your code

1. In order for this to work you need to define a no-argument constructor for `ColumnAttribute`.
2. The type of `Index` and `Name` is `int option` and `string option` respectively but you need it to be `int` and `string`.

Try the following

```
type ColumnAttribute(index:int option,name:string option) =     
    inherit Attribute()     
    let mutable index = index
    let mutable name = name
    new () = ColumnAttribute (None, None)
    member x.Index          
        with get() = match index with | Some i -> i | None -> 0
        and set value = index <- Some value         
    member x.Name          
        with get() = match name with | Some n -> n | None -> ""
        and set value = name <- Some value  

type Substance = {     
    [<Column(Index=1)>] Name : string     
    [<Column(Index=0)>] Id : int     
    [<Column(Name="sequence")>] Sequence : string }
```

Comment: this doesn't work neither. Does this szenario really work in fsharp? hmmm. it's really odd. what I really would like to have is an Attribute with an option. So I guess I have to create a nullable (or use pseudo nullables, e.g. for Index -1 and for Name the EmptyString). My intention is to use the two attributes as option either the index or the Name to identify a column in a csv file

Comment: @Rainer, I'm not sure what you mean by "this doesn't work".  I've suceesfully compiled this in Visual Studio 2010 RTM

Comment: ah ok. tried it again in a clean script. now it works! I think its a matter of how I'm using the attributes. I really was curious about why this didn't work. I know you have a really good knowledge of fsharp. Guess it's an error related to how I use the attribute. Will check my codebase again!

Comment: So, seems like it is a VS bug or something related. Can't reproduce the error any more. As this is really the clean way to do it in fsharp with real options, I'll switch to this solution as correct answer! Thanks again.

Comment: You can replace `match index with Some i -> i | None -> 0` with `defaultArg index 0`.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
type ColumnAttribute() =
    inherit System.Attribute()
    let mutable index = 0
    let mutable name = ""
    member x.Index 
        with get() = index
        and set value = index <- value
    member x.Name 
        with get() = name
        and set value = name <- value

type Substance = {
    [<Column(Index=1)>] Name : string
    [<Column(Index=0)>] Id : int
    [<Column(Name="sequence")>] Sequence : string
}
```

Attributes already support property setter syntax similar to named arguments. To get what you want, use a parameterless constructor and rely on the attribute syntax, instead of named arguments (which don't work well with attributes anyway, because they're inferred as `option`s...which don't qualify as constant expressions).

Comment: I usee let mutable index = -1 because columns can be 0 based, and I do have to have an option between index and column. So does a nullable work on an attribute or is this they way to it. The MSDN isn't very clear about this statement as they suggest to use positional arguments and a property getter/setter approach. thx anyway. this works. I was so keen on using options that I forgot about the easy way.

Comment: @Rainer - you're running into a CLR limitation.  When represented in the metadata, attributes' constructor parameters (and field/property setters) can only contain values of types `System.Type`, `string`, `char`, `bool`, `float`, `float32`, integral types, enums, or arrays of those types.  Since there is no way to store values of type `string option` or `int option` in the attribute metadata, you will have to use an approach like Daniel's.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
open System

type ColumnAttribute() =
    inherit Attribute()
    let mutable index = 0
    let mutable name = ""
    member x.Index         
        with get() = index        
        and set value = index <- value        
    member x.Name         
        with get() = name        
        and set value = name <- value

type Substance = {    
    [<Column(Index=1)>] Name : string    
    [<Column(Index=0)>] Id : int    
    [<Column(Name="sequence")>] Sequence : string
}
```

Note that the optional parameters (e.g. `?index`) in your original attempt were causing the types to be e.g. `int option` rather than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using the alternative syntax documented for [optional arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters)

```ml
type NamedAttribute([<Optional>] [<DefaultParameterValue("")>] name) = 
    inherit Attribute()
    new () = new NamedAttribute(?name = None)
    member val Name:string = name

module X = 
    [<Command(name = "")>]
    let f x = x
```